# Difference between != and <>

Tags: php

I've always been using `!=` as "not equal to" in C++ and PHP. I just realized `<>` does the same thing. What's the difference?

Just in case if there is no difference, why does `<>` exist?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, just different syntax

> $a != $b  Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
>
> $a <> $b  Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.

Source: [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

They are the [same](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
$a != $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a <> $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
```